# Disentangle doubly linked data

Tags: code-golf, data-structures

A doubly linked list is a data structure in which each node has a `value` as well as "links" to both the `previous` and next `nodes` in the list. For example, consider the following nodes with values 12, 99, and 37:

[image]

Here, the nodes with values **12** and **99** point to their respective `next` nodes, with values **99** and **37**. The node with value **37** has no `next` pointer because it's the last node in the list. Likewise, the nodes with values **99** and **37** point to their respective `previous` nodes, **12** and **99**, but **12** has no `previous` pointer because it's the first node in the list.

### The setup

In practice, a node's "links" are implemented as pointers to the previous and next node's locations in memory. For our purposes, the "memory" will be an array of nodes and a node's location will be its index in the array. A node can be thought of as a 3-tuple of the form `( prev value next )`. The above example, then, might look like this:

[image]

But it might look like this, instead:

[image]

Starting at any node, you can follow `previous` links (shown as the origins of the red arrows) to get to the nodes that precede it and `next` links (green arrows) to find subsequent nodes in order to get all of the nodes' values in order: `[12, 99, 37]`.

The first diagram above could be represented in an array as `[[null, 12, 1], [0, 99, 2], [1, 37, null]]`. The second, then, would be `[[2, 99, 1], [0, 37, null], [null, 12, 0]]`.

### The challenge

> Write a program that takes as input an array of nodes and the index of a node and returns, in list order, the values of the nodes in the same doubly linked list.

#### A complication

The "memory" won't always contain the nodes of just one list. It might contain several lists:

[image]

The above array contains three doubly linked lists, color-coded for your convenience:

1. The nodes at indexes `7`, `10`, `1`, `4`, `3`, `12` (showing only `next` links to reduce clutter; click to enlarge):

   [image]

   Given this array and any of these indexes, your program should return, in order, the values `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]`.
2. The node at index `9`:

   [image]

   Given the index `9`, your program should return `[99]`.
3. The nodes at indexes `11`, `8`, `0`, `6`, `2`:

   [image]

   Given one of these indexes, it should return `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]`.

### Rules

#### Input

Your program will receive as input:

1. A list of  nodes (3-tuples as described above), where 1 ≤  ≤ 1,000, in any convenient format, e.g. an array of arrays, a "flat" array of integers with length 3, etc.

   The 3-tuples' elements may be in any order: `( prev value next )`, `( next prev value )`, etc. For each node, `prev` and `next` will be `null` (or another convenient value, e.g. `-1`), indicating the first or last node in a doubly linked list, or a valid index of the list, either 0- or 1-based as is convenient. `value` will be a signed 32-bit integer or the largest integer type your language supports, whichever is smaller.
2. The index  of a node in the list (1). The indicated node may be the first node in a doubly linked list, the last node, a middle node, or even the only node.

The input list (1) **may contain pathological data** (e.g. cycles, nodes pointed to by multiple other nodes, etc.), but the input index (2) will always point to a node from which a single, well-formed output can be deduced.

#### Output

Your program should output the values of the nodes of the doubly linked list of which the node at index  is a member, in list order. Output can be in any convenient format, but its data must include only the node `value`s.

#### Winning

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes apply.

### Test cases

Below, each test case is of the form:

```
X)
prev value next, prev value next, ...
index
value value value ...
```

...where `X` is a letter to identify the test case, the second line is the input list, the third line is the 0-based input index, and the fourth line is the output.

```
A) null 12 1, 0 99 2, 1 37 null
   1
   12 99 37

B) 2 99 1, 0 37 null, null 12 0
   1
   12 99 37

C) 8 5 6, 10 1 4, 6 11 null, 4 3 12, 1 2 3, 12 8 null, 0 7 2, null 0 10, 11 3 0, null 99 null, 7 1 1, null 2 8, 3 5 5
   4
   0 1 1 2 3 5 8

D) 8 5 6, 10 1 4, 6 11 null, 4 3 12, 1 2 3, 12 8 null, 0 7 2, null 0 10, 11 3 0, null 99 null, 7 1 1, null 2 8, 3 5 5
   0
   2 3 5 7 11

E) 8 5 6, 10 1 4, 6 11 null, 4 3 12, 1 2 3, 12 8 null, 0 7 2, null 0 10, 11 3 0, null 99 null, 7 1 1, null 2 8, 3 5 5
   9
   99

F) 13 80 18, 18 71 null, 5 10 19, 12 1 8, 19 21 null, 31 6 2, 17 5 26, 26 0 30, 3 -1 25, null 1 23, 27 6 17, 14 1 24, 28 -1 3, null 80 0, 20 4 11, 33 6 29, 24 9 33, 10 7 6, 0 67 1, 2 15 4, 32 1 14, null 1 31, 29 3 null, 9 -1 28, 11 5 16, 8 1 null, 6 3 7, null 8 10, 23 1 12, 15 5 22, 7 9 null, 21 3 5, null 3 20, 16 2 15
   18
   80 80 67 71

G) 13 80 18, 18 71 null, 5 10 19, 12 1 8, 19 21 null, 31 6 2, 17 5 26, 26 0 30, 3 -1 25, null 1 23, 27 6 17, 14 1 24, 28 -1 3, null 80 0, 20 4 11, 33 6 29, 24 9 33, 10 7 6, 0 67 1, 2 15 4, 32 1 14, null 1 31, 29 3 null, 9 -1 28, 11 5 16, 8 1 null, 6 3 7, null 8 10, 23 1 12, 15 5 22, 7 9 null, 21 3 5, null 3 20, 16 2 15
   8
   1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1

H) 13 80 18, 18 71 null, 5 10 19, 12 1 8, 19 21 null, 31 6 2, 17 5 26, 26 0 30, 3 -1 25, null 1 23, 27 6 17, 14 1 24, 28 -1 3, null 80 0, 20 4 11, 33 6 29, 24 9 33, 10 7 6, 0 67 1, 2 15 4, 32 1 14, null 1 31, 29 3 null, 9 -1 28, 11 5 16, 8 1 null, 6 3 7, null 8 10, 23 1 12, 15 5 22, 7 9 null, 21 3 5, null 3 20, 16 2 15
   4
   1 3 6 10 15 21

I) 13 80 18, 18 71 null, 5 10 19, 12 1 8, 19 21 null, 31 6 2, 17 5 26, 26 0 30, 3 -1 25, null 1 23, 27 6 17, 14 1 24, 28 -1 3, null 80 0, 20 4 11, 33 6 29, 24 9 33, 10 7 6, 0 67 1, 2 15 4, 32 1 14, null 1 31, 29 3 null, 9 -1 28, 11 5 16, 8 1 null, 6 3 7, null 8 10, 23 1 12, 15 5 22, 7 9 null, 21 3 5, null 3 20, 16 2 15
   14
   3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3

J) 13 80 18, 18 71 null, 5 10 19, 12 1 8, 19 21 null, 31 6 2, 17 5 26, 26 0 30, 3 -1 25, null 1 23, 27 6 17, 14 1 24, 28 -1 3, null 80 0, 20 4 11, 33 6 29, 24 9 33, 10 7 6, 0 67 1, 2 15 4, 32 1 14, null 1 31, 29 3 null, 9 -1 28, 11 5 16, 8 1 null, 6 3 7, null 8 10, 23 1 12, 15 5 22, 7 9 null, 21 3 5, null 3 20, 16 2 15
   17
   8 6 7 5 3 0 9

K) 4 11 0, null 22 3, null 33 3, 1 44 4, 3 55 null, 7 66 7, 6 77 6
   3
   22 44 55

L) null -123 null
   0
   -123
```

Comment: Sandbox link: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14451/11261

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32687/convert-binary-search-tree-into-ordered-linked-list

Comment: Is input as three arrays (one containing all predecessor nodes in order, one values, and one successor nodes) allowed, or is that too far from the concept of tuples?

Comment: @Sanchises Sorry, too far for me.

Comment: That's all right! I thought so, but I wanted to be ahead of any comments on my answer saying I could shave off two bytes taking separate arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

```
è[¬D0‹#Isè]\[`sˆD0‹#Isè]¯
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVAxTgRBDOt5xUi0g7SZ7O7M9tfwhmElQOIF9wEq3nIFEjXtXckv@MhiO9zqOie2EyfD9PJqb9t2OfXz52H4ff@@fzxeTutTfz7@fNw0zl/bZuNd7@Y5tSEna2tO3VpO1XJ6MFYT2qQWUQUIWuElp7LLHGhGQ0zNCbYysyjowu@DVJSDmVgQsXDJqvxWNWAMZhTTwuRXD5NqWgGgMgJ4BFDOgjbiuTyMz@nEgDOwHLwFMbXE4zAbb4J5qDjneuXynz8eYDrTNLjJEqpZjrrn5Qc1ymNJPGmKJ6moihtu/hTC/UXARXbjecy8rn8)

### Explanation

```
è[¬D0‹#Isè]\[`sˆD0‹#Isè]¯   # Arguments n, a
è                           # Get element at index n in a
 [¬D0‹#Isè]                 # Find the first element in the list
 [                          # While true, do
  ¬                         #   Head (get index of previous element)
   D0‹#                     #   Break if lower than 0
       Isè                  #   Get the element at that index
          ]                 # End loop
           \                # Delete top element of stack
            [`sˆD0‹#Isè]    # Iterate through list
            [               # While true, do
             `sˆ            #   Add value to global array and keep next index on stack
                D0‹#Isè     #   Same as above
                       ]    # End loop
                        ¯   # Push global array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>79</s> <s>65</s> <s>59</s> 55 bytes

**-6** bytes thanks to [Brute Force](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bruce-forte).

```hs
x#i|let-1!d=[];i!d=i:x!!i!!d!d=[x!!i!!1|i<-last(i!0)!2]
```

Defines function `#` that accepts a list of lists of integers, where `null` is represented as `-1`, and returns list of node values.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VZLasMwEN3nFDLpIgEZrJEs2W3TG/QErimBBiqahFB7kUXuns5HckJvYEjAeCTPm3nzngj63g4/u/3@ej0v42W/G0tTfG26/iXiKz6fiyIWxRdtSWgu8bXcb4dxFYtqXUB/PWzjUW3UYXt6/1Srj9V50CquVfmmTr/xOKondR6WuDHuhnFYLBb8RkC3UPhbdV1ptDKAT69VV2nVtloBxbhvg1al6XFl1joDQHJyfsrBRa5U/QM0WtVaea6JAMxyFHsMTcY6LETo1BirWA4xaHIOYkPiRq2oVMVJhsFV/kDsBBG420SOilFsmVBNNN08aFbzoNneaBrcbqgo5xhsGyZ6NfXCp82kTCpl6OxNaRYjnw9j4C7Ac4NnvrZK7ZlNPR1BXPC4EBhvAhdw8oXFgkZANmOIKVcDDChTCFghwDwBt5GetVn5kFzA0IekC81SJ0esDGbcHTErWS1LLFO2iX@TxSd1uHDDEMnyjAgT3@wWWGkiItUiEiS3JudAPJ0kwhjEbM8@GnbPNA/7Zmzfw705u@ce7s35r/Nh36ztCzf7nFykpvsPwJ1apItNtyrn8rhYv767JHmf@NKbtcKFvXUoeTaw@W5drflLf/0D)

### Explanation

```hs
let-1!d=[];i!d=i:x!!i!!d!d
```

Define function `!` that iterates through the nodes starting at node `i` and returns a list visited indexes.
It accepts the second argument `d` that specifies which index of the "tuple" use as the index of the next node (`d==2` to iterate forwards, `d==0` to iterate backwards).

```hs
(i!0)
```

Iterate backwards starting from the given index and return visited indexes.

```hs
last(i!0)
```

Take last visited index, which is the beginning of the list.

```hs
last(i!0)!2
```

Iterate from the beginning of the list.

```hs
[x!!i!!1|i<-last(i!0)!2]
```

Replace each visited index with the value of the node.

Comment: You could *almost* write `x!!i!!1` as `i!1!!1`, but it breaks because of `-1` in the outputs. If you just choose another sentinel value to represent `null` (say, `-9`), it’ll work, but it’ll always break for _some_ input, which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
l,n=input()
while~n:m=n;n=l[n][0]
while~m:p,v,m=l[m];print v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NCgMhDITvfYocW8iCuu4/Pol4LKygqZTtll766jZKvX2TmUmSPsf@IJVzQDKe0uu43i7v3Yf7l9ZoaCMTLDkr3H8a14QnRp5Gt6WnpwPOnK2dEQaE0SFYKRAkgi48MjJ3sgiN0LNWNYSgWFZkmFuGuxNbBTvOlFWihmQti2YsS2tM9ZpsRllWuK8PDc6h/gE)

This is pretty much Chas Brown's answer, minus these golfs:

- I reuse n, saving an assignment
- I store the last valid n in m, allowing me to
- place the print after the assignment in line 3, saving me the final print
- I use only ~n instead of -~n, because negative values are just as truthy as positive ones, saving me 2 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>94</s> <s>90</s> 88 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$l[_,u,v]|v<0=[u]=[u: $l(l!!v)]
?l= $l o until((>)0o hd)((!!)l o hd)o(!!)l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NasMwEITvfoo1yUEGGaTE@St1ckkPhd5yFCII220EshRi2aTQZ6@6UvFB8M3O7Goa0ykbeteOpoNeaRt0f3cPDxffvtkpWxpxpSOd5M/0ymoxSnwvsDTE5PlUyOxkalTgYLReG0KOBXNwawtC8ryIc2SXOFy8evhsAUYPHmoQYk9hQ2ErKQjOKHAKVeQtInLJo6gorFGvUojCCmVChP2cwd0dWhFLzMRTLIV4WmazcTjMG7v0G5@NeCzyOhXaSIkttW27J9asshpO/53TKPw2n0Z9DaF8/wjnb6t63Qx/)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 39 bytes

```
XHx`HwI3$)t]x6Mt`Hwl3$)tbhwt]x4L)Hw2I$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxCsMwEAT7vGILNyIYdDpJttEHZEj6gBEkqVI4nUD@vXy@apnZ3f@n7r2/8vHObeXB1HLEZxXYL/j@mgj/MLm5dTC9bwQLKvdtRkBMICH4hAgijJTgwSAnBRxYwmFWbzFB9Kh/m645w6pYFl1M8iEV8knSBoRy4xM)

Almost a direct port of my Octave answer, but this version finds the end first, and then works it way back, rather than the other way round, which saved one byte.

```
XHx           % Store array in H.
`HwI3$)t]     % Work to the end of the array
x6Mt          % Delete the end of array delimiter, and push the array end index twice
`Hwl3$)    t] % Work to the beginning of the array
       tbhw   % Append all indices found.
Hw2I$)        % Index into original array.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>81</s> 77 bytes

```python
a,n=input()
u=a[n][0]
while-~u:u,v,w=a[u]
while-~w:print v;u,v,w=a[w]
print v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5LCsMgEIb3nmKWLYygxjxLTiIusihEKFZKjHTTq9tRanff/xoN72N/epXzhn51PsTjcmVx3Yy3RliWdve4809cIp6YyI5/Ly3h5fwB561lybKflbMxE0KPMFgEIwWCRNCFB0JiLovQCB1pVUsIimRFgql1aDtSVJBTp5wStSTrWLRgnttirK/JFpRjhbv6od5a1F8)

EDIT: Thx to Mr. Xcoder for 4 bytes...

Takes a list of tuples [u,v,w] where u and w are -1 to represent the beginning/end of the linked list segment.

Comment: 77 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5LCsMgEIb3nmKWLYygxjxLTiIusihEKFZKjHTTq9tRanff/xoN72N/epXzhn51PsTjcmVx3Yy3RliWdve4809cIp6YyI5/Ly3h5fwB561lybKflbMxE0KPMFgEIwWCRNCFB0JiLovQCB1pVUsIimRFgql1aDtSVJBTp5wStSTrWLRgnttirK/JFpRjhbv6od5a1F8 "Python 2 – Try It Online"). Booleans are subclasses of int so only `0` is Falsy, and therefore `u>=0` can be golfed to `u+1` and this can be further shortened to `-~u` to remove the whitespace.

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder - Yes, quite right!

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 132 bytes

```
<?list(,$x,$y)=$argv;parse_str($x);while(($q=$x[$y*3+1])>=0)$y=$q;do{$n[]=$x[$y*3+2];$y=$x[$y*3];}while($x[$y*3]);echo join(' ',$n);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLRboMwDPyVPkQt2UAiCRBQyvYhFZqqDRWmCiigDjTt15dt2EyOeLIuZ9/ZB13VWXt8vtbD6Pls8tnMc3buL3fTnfuhfBnG3mMTNx9VfS09j91yNp3Y/KAeRcGf8pCzOWc389Z@suZU/JOyMH8EoMJ8wfiKuSlfq3b33taNd9gdfNZwY62dfgVEul@KWkoaLiUQe8JpRNlSYgDQiMMSijML3RIQNCgACTxBEZqoqpBSCJCi4tJBggpJTT0ioCLSB6MypQrO1ZiBQCtAoCDhKKWIBwK0ygiDGWliDi@JpproFtNVFU1Uie21axDZ9qbM6U7oMbFzJ5GjoSm6vNsrafq4AW4abw00WSemf4OiyQb0bU0BP58V0XfbjXXbDDZofgA)

Input is taken as a querystring `x[]=-1&x[]=1&x[]=1...` (all nodes in a flat array), in the order of `next`, `prev`, then `value` for each node with -1 used for ending nodes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>81</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```matlab
function o=f(a,n)while q=a(n,1)o=a(n=q,2);end
while n=a(n,3)o=[o a(n,2)];end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCoMwEEX3fsXdFJQqZKJWJbizf9CduLAaW6EkiPbx93aSrrqamXPuZeyw9S@9N3VLEKDu2JbIcVIgvpApnECEhBQypCDJAhIpD4nSc4ECjBPfF8rFUwgPqsonCu6QB9xRbHPkncIBlFz7VY@Yzag/s7nt09MM22wNbD2FfWyi931@aCx1H5qYIutmvcQyUtqMwU8aL1OWrYVbZdQ5vbvIFDbc41cXvW4DP0MTHDwUf/Qc7F8)

Rather straightforward version. Explanation is left as an exercise to the reader. A much more *fun* version is presented below:

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>142</s> <s>99</s> 92 bytes

```matlab
@(a,n)[(p=@(b,c,z){q=a(z,2),@()[b(b,c,a(z,c)),q]}{2-~a(z,c)}())(p,1,n),p(p,3,n)(end-1:-1:1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NasMwEITveYq5FLRUMlo5zp8w@OC@QW/GB/8oIRfHIaGUhPTV1Y1yCizszLcz7Gm4dj8h1mXDsOD2s9mgwMqDxWHpsQIzDHsskYOdHOCQy3LYJG6xhmCT@tY/4zlsAtttSqylwwlIx8u1QNF6fIBN313CiOM0ht/jdFjsyyzLYqU6PVGj5rJSvR70je7nslM37UhXipo@0ScYiPS5fdyd@XvZhyJSs2bp61lELkKFaTS8k2Fq417Vmkmef4fLdZD3qBeJ2Tf4FeM/)

Yo, I heard you liked anonymous functions...

Takes a `nx3` array, with the first column the predecessor, second column the value, and third value the successor nodes. All the node indices are 1-based, which is the default in Octave.

```matlab
% Create an anonymous function, taking an array a and first node n
@(a,n)
% Returns an array containing the predecessor and sucessor nodes
      [                                                                     ,                     ]
% Defines an recursive anonymous function (by supplying itself to the local namespace)
% which looks at the first column (c=1) or last column (c=3) of the input array to get the next nodes
       (p=@(p,c,z)                                                   )(p,1,n)
% Create a cell array, either containing the end node,
                    {q=a(z,2),                       
% ...or an array with all next  next nodes and the current node
% (note the use of an anonymous function taking no parameters to defer array access, in case of the last node)                
                              @()[p(p,c,a(z,c)),q]}
% depending whether the next node number is nonzero (followed by () to execute the deferred array access)
                                                    {2-~a(z,c)}()
% Do the same with c=3, reverse (function p builds the array right-to-left) and drop the current node to prevent a duplicate.                                                                             
                                                                             p(p,3,n)(end-1:-1:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 85 bytes

```kotlin
{g,S->generateSequence(generateSequence(S){g[it][0]}.last()){g[it][2]}.map{g[it][1]}}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
{g,S->
    generateSequence(generateSequence(S){g[it][0]}.last()){ g[it][2]}.map { g[it][1] }
}
```

### Test

```kotlin
typealias Node=Triple<Int?,Int?,Int?>
data class Test(val input: List<Node>, val start:Int, val result: List<Int>)
val TEST = listOf<Test>(
Test(
listOf(Node(null, 12, 1), Node(0, 99, 2), Node(1, 37, null)),
1,
listOf(12, 99, 37)
),
Test(listOf(
Node(2, 99, 1), Node(0, 37, null), Node(null, 12, 0)),
1,
listOf(12, 99, 37)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(8, 5, 6), Node(10, 1, 4), Node(6, 11, null), Node(4, 3, 12), Node(1, 2, 3), Node(12, 8, null), Node(0, 7, 2), Node(null, 0, 10), Node(11, 3, 0), Node(null, 99, null), Node(7, 1, 1), Node(null, 2, 8), Node(3, 5, 5)),
4,
listOf(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(8, 5, 6), Node(10, 1, 4), Node(6, 11, null), Node(4, 3, 12), Node(1, 2, 3), Node(12, 8, null), Node(0, 7, 2), Node(null, 0, 10), Node(11, 3, 0), Node(null, 99, null), Node(7, 1, 1), Node(null, 2, 8), Node(3, 5, 5)),
0,
listOf(2, 3, 5, 7, 11)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(8, 5, 6), Node(10, 1, 4), Node(6, 11, null), Node(4, 3, 12), Node(1, 2, 3), Node(12, 8, null), Node(0, 7, 2), Node(null, 0, 10), Node(11, 3, 0), Node(null, 99, null), Node(7, 1, 1), Node(null, 2, 8), Node(3, 5, 5)),
9,
listOf(99)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(13, 80, 18), Node(18, 71, null), Node(5, 10, 19), Node(12, 1, 8), Node(19, 21, null), Node(31, 6, 2), Node(17, 5, 26), Node(26, 0, 30), Node(3, -1, 25), Node(null, 1, 23), Node(27, 6, 17), Node(14, 1, 24), Node(28, -1, 3), Node(null, 80, 0), Node(20, 4, 11), Node(33, 6, 29), Node(24, 9, 33), Node(10, 7, 6), Node(0, 67, 1), Node(2, 15, 4), Node(32, 1, 14), Node(null, 1, 31), Node(29, 3, null), Node(9, -1, 28), Node(11, 5, 16), Node(8, 1, null), Node(6, 3, 7), Node(null, 8, 10), Node(23, 1, 12), Node(15, 5, 22), Node(7, 9, null), Node(21, 3, 5), Node(null, 3, 20), Node(16, 2, 15)),
18,
listOf(80, 80, 67, 71)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(13, 80, 18), Node(18, 71, null), Node(5, 10, 19), Node(12, 1, 8), Node(19, 21, null), Node(31, 6, 2), Node(17, 5, 26), Node(26, 0, 30), Node(3, -1, 25), Node(null, 1, 23), Node(27, 6, 17), Node(14, 1, 24), Node(28, -1, 3), Node(null, 80, 0), Node(20, 4, 11), Node(33, 6, 29), Node(24, 9, 33), Node(10, 7, 6), Node(0, 67, 1), Node(2, 15, 4), Node(32, 1, 14), Node(null, 1, 31), Node(29, 3, null), Node(9, -1, 28), Node(11, 5, 16), Node(8, 1, null), Node(6, 3, 7), Node(null, 8, 10), Node(23, 1, 12), Node(15, 5, 22), Node(7, 9, null), Node(21, 3, 5), Node(null, 3, 20), Node(16, 2, 15)),
8,
listOf(1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(13, 80, 18), Node(18, 71, null), Node(5, 10, 19), Node(12, 1, 8), Node(19, 21, null), Node(31, 6, 2), Node(17, 5, 26), Node(26, 0, 30), Node(3, -1, 25), Node(null, 1, 23), Node(27, 6, 17), Node(14, 1, 24), Node(28, -1, 3), Node(null, 80, 0), Node(20, 4, 11), Node(33, 6, 29), Node(24, 9, 33), Node(10, 7, 6), Node(0, 67, 1), Node(2, 15, 4), Node(32, 1, 14), Node(null, 1, 31), Node(29, 3, null), Node(9, -1, 28), Node(11, 5, 16), Node(8, 1, null), Node(6, 3, 7), Node(null, 8, 10), Node(23, 1, 12), Node(15, 5, 22), Node(7, 9, null), Node(21, 3, 5), Node(null, 3, 20), Node(16, 2, 15)),
4,
listOf(1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(13, 80, 18), Node(18, 71, null), Node(5, 10, 19), Node(12, 1, 8), Node(19, 21, null), Node(31, 6, 2), Node(17, 5, 26), Node(26, 0, 30), Node(3, -1, 25), Node(null, 1, 23), Node(27, 6, 17), Node(14, 1, 24), Node(28, -1, 3), Node(null, 80, 0), Node(20, 4, 11), Node(33, 6, 29), Node(24, 9, 33), Node(10, 7, 6), Node(0, 67, 1), Node(2, 15, 4), Node(32, 1, 14), Node(null, 1, 31), Node(29, 3, null), Node(9, -1, 28), Node(11, 5, 16), Node(8, 1, null), Node(6, 3, 7), Node(null, 8, 10), Node(23, 1, 12), Node(15, 5, 22), Node(7, 9, null), Node(21, 3, 5), Node(null, 3, 20), Node(16, 2, 15)),
14,
listOf(3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(13, 80, 18), Node(18, 71, null), Node(5, 10, 19), Node(12, 1, 8), Node(19, 21, null), Node(31, 6, 2), Node(17, 5, 26), Node(26, 0, 30), Node(3, -1, 25), Node(null, 1, 23), Node(27, 6, 17), Node(14, 1, 24), Node(28, -1, 3), Node(null, 80, 0), Node(20, 4, 11), Node(33, 6, 29), Node(24, 9, 33), Node(10, 7, 6), Node(0, 67, 1), Node(2, 15, 4), Node(32, 1, 14), Node(null, 1, 31), Node(29, 3, null), Node(9, -1, 28), Node(11, 5, 16), Node(8, 1, null), Node(6, 3, 7), Node(null, 8, 10), Node(23, 1, 12), Node(15, 5, 22), Node(7, 9, null), Node(21, 3, 5), Node(null, 3, 20), Node(16, 2, 15)),
17,
listOf(8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(4, 11, 0), Node(null, 22, 3), Node(null, 33, 3), Node(1, 44, 4), Node(3, 55, null), Node(7, 66, 7), Node(6, 77, 6)),
3,
listOf(22, 44, 55)
),
Test(
listOf(Node(null, -123, null)),
0,
listOf(-123)
)
)

var f:(List<List<Int?>>,Int)-> Sequence<Int?> =
{g,S->generateSequence(generateSequence(S){g[it][0]}.last()){g[it][2]}.map{g[it][1]}}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for ((input, start, result) in TEST) {
        val out = f(input.map { it.toList() }, start).toList()
        if (out != result) {
            throw AssertionError("$input $start $result $out")
        }
    }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##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)

Comment: I just wish generateSequence was shorter

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>70</s> 63 Bytes

```
(x,i,a)=>(h=_=>i&&h(a(x[i].v),i=x[i].n))(x.map(_=>i=x[i].p||i))
```

Test case:

```
F([undefined,{p:0,v:12,n:2},{p:1,v:99,n:3},{p:2,v:37,n:0}],1,alert)
```

Comment: The `alert` needs to be in the main body of your function and counted towards your byte total.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11324/76323

Comment: +10 / -9 is not a consensus.

Comment: I don't see the exact + and - s. Also, it's javascript's intended output way, and only way when output have some delay